# NLP: can I use RNN if word order is NOT important? Or is CNN better?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, natural-language, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I want to match users to job posts, hoping to write a neural network to pick up on keywords users are looking for. My initial thinking was recurrent neural networks (RNNs) since we're dealing with language-modeling. But keyword positions shouldn't be important (keyword invariance). Eg, both the following job titles should match positive:

- "Seeking React, React Native, Node, Postgres developer."
- "Senior web developer. We use Node and React. Ideally also familiar with PostgreSQL."

My guess is that RNNs won't work here, and I should use CNNs instead since invariance is its specialty (at least with images). Alternatively, any other better-suited models than RNNs or CNNs?

Comment: Well, according to the book "Deep Learning" of Goodfellow et al. CNN's are appropriate for topologic-structured data (in example, images), while RNN's are the better choice when it comes to label sequence-structured data (in example, text). Can you elaborate what kind of structure your input has?

Answer (score 6):

If order truly isn't necessary, recurrent neural networks might be the wrong tool to use altogether. I would recommend representing the job postings as [bags-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) or [document vectors](https://deeplearning4j.org/doc2vec.html) and performing another neural network architecture or simple nearest-neighbor search to start with.

Comment: Only recurrent neural networks assume an ordering in the inputs. Feedforward neural networks are just as capable as nearest-neighbor to work with bag-of-words.

Comment: Starting simple though is a good advice.

Comment: Yes but he specifically asked about CNNs, which have certain spacial arrangement/invariance assumptions baked into them, which don't apply to arbitrary BOW vectors. And if he were to use a fully-connected network instead, then a single network layer will need to contain ~vocab_size^2 many weights, which is likely to be impractical large.